# Where to find a list of all the possible HTML tags in Python?

Tags: python, html, tags

Is there a standard module in Python that lists all the HTML tags?

For example, I would like to do things like:

```
if is_valid_html_tag('div'):
   print 'div is a valid tag'

if is_not_valid_html_tag('boda'):
   print 'boda is not a valid tag'
```

To do this I need a list of all tags in Python. I wonder if someone has assembled them already or maybe included in xml or some other html module in Python library?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: What do you need this for? Does it need to be Python? Does this help: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

Comment: What do you mean? All the HTML tags that are used in a given document?

Comment: Do you want to parse a html document with python or do you just need a list of valid html tags (which would have nothing to do with python)?

Comment: shouldn't you look at the W3C website?

Comment: This isn't really a sensible Python question.  HTML tags are defined by the W3C.  Why did you label this [Python]?

Comment: S.Lott: The question is - is there a Python module that lists all the HTML tags.

Comment: Tim Pietzcker: Just the HTML tags. So I could do things like `if is_tag('html'): print "html is valid HTML tag"` and `if is_not_tag('boda'): print "boda is not a valid HTML tag"`

Comment: poke, I just need a list of valid html tags. (since python has all kinds of modules - smtp, xml, etc, the question asks if there is a module like `htmltags` that would list all the valid html tags.) (for example, `boda` is not a valid html tag but `div` is.) (I would like to use this in Python code to detect if a tag is a valid HTML tag or not.) (For example, `if is_tag('div'): print "div is a valid html tag"` and `if not is_tag('boda'): print "boda is not a valid html tag"`.

Comment: GregS, I have now improved the question.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know whether there is a built in module that does just that. I'd suggest finding a list of tags, then writing a function like this...

```
def is_valid_html_tag(tag_name):  
  tags=["a","abbr","acronym","address","area","b","base","bdo","big","blockquote","body","br","button","caption","cite","code","col","colgroup","dd","del","dfn","div","dl","DOCTYPE","dt","em","fieldset","form","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","head","html","hr","i","img","input","ins","kbd","label","legend","li","link","map","meta","noscript","object","ol","optgroup","option","p","param","pre","q","samp","script","select","small","span","strong","style","sub","sup","table","tbody","td","textarea","tfoot","th","thead","title","tr","tt","ul","var"]
  return tag_name in tags
```

I think the list of valid tags depends on your doctype. These came from http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/. They say this list is for Strict XHTML.

That said, there may be a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do. I'm sure the friendly folks here would be happy to help if you'd like to provide more details on your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll improve it by finding all other possible tags. 

The goal is just that - determine if the given string is a valid HTML tag.

Comment: That return statement seems more complicated than necessary.  Wouldn't `return tag_name in tags` be just as good?  I'd also suggest making `tags` a set rather than a list, to improve lookup speed.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson good point, that part is convoluted for no apparent reason.  Thanks for the tip about the sets too, I'm fairly new to Python and haven't used that data structure before.

Comment: I'd also suggest building the set ONCE, not every time the function is called.

Answer (score 3):

Use this: https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/blob/master/html5lib/sanitizer.py

```
from html5lib.sanitizer import HTMLSanitizerMixin
print(HTMLSanitizerMixin.acceptable_elements)
```

Comment: It's not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can wget or download this json:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/html-tags/blob/main/html-tags.json

or

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
  
# import json
import json
# store the URL in url as 
# parameter for urlopen
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindresorhus/html-tags/main/html-tags.json"
  
# store the response of URL
response = urlopen(url)
  
# storing the JSON response 
# from url in data
data_json = json.loads(response.read())
  
# print the json response
print(data_json)
```